# Pandas / Wrong date format when reading Excel file

Tags: pandas

I am reading an excel files :

```
dfEx=pd.read_excel(fileExcel, engine='openpyxl')
```

There is a date column in Object format, and `dfEx["Date"]` gives me these results :

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 15/10/2022 10:44:59 |
| 1 | 15/10/2022 10:47:53 |
| 2 | 15/10/2022 10:49:50 |
| 3 | 15/10/2022 10:50:40 |
| 4 | 15/10/2022 10:54:05 |
|  | ... |
| 174 | 2022-10-16 00:00:00 |
| 175 | 2022-10-16 00:00:00 |
| 176 | 2022-10-16 00:00:00 |
| 177 | 2022-10-16 00:00:00 |
| 178 | 2022-10-16 00:00:00 |

I don't get why I have the format change between the beginning and the end, as in the Excel file the separator character is always / for year/month/day

The syntax I have in the Excel file is :

> 15/10/2022 11:13:64

for the first and

> 15-10-2022

for the rest

So when I use the datetime function it doesn't work :

```
dfEx['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(dfEx['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', exact=False)
```

> ValueError: time data '2022-10-15 00:00:00' does not match format
> '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' (search)

Comment: A workaround could be to read that column from excel as a `str` and convert it in a second step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `errors='coerce'` for missing values if no match format `15/10/2022 10:44:59` and then replace missing values by another `to_datetime` for convert format `2022-10-16 00:00:00`:

```
dfEx['date'] = (pd.to_datetime(dfEx['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
                  .fillna(pd.to_datetime(dfEx['date'], errors='coerce')))
print (dfEx)
   id                 date
0    0 2022-10-15 10:44:59
1    1 2022-10-15 10:47:53
2    2 2022-10-15 10:49:50
3    3 2022-10-15 10:50:40
4    4 2022-10-15 10:54:05
5  174 2022-10-16 00:00:00
6  175 2022-10-16 00:00:00
7  176 2022-10-16 00:00:00
8  177 2022-10-16 00:00:00
9  178 2022-10-16 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have two different dates formats in excel:

- Ones with dashes  `2022-10-16 00:00:00`
- Others with slashes `15/10/2022 10:54:05`

So you cannot parse all the dates at once, you first have to split the dataframes:

```
df_slashes = df[df.Date.str.contains("/", regex=False))
df_dashes = df[df.Date.str.contains("-", regex=False))
```

Then for each dataframe run the corresponding `to_datetime` function:

```py
df_slashes_dates = pd.to_datetime(df_slashes.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
df_dashes_dates = pd.to_datetime(df_dashes.Date, format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Finally do whatever you want with these two series.